# Calculate the number of ocurrences separated by the values of two columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Having the following csv I need to calculate the number of persons in each state separated by gender using bash creating a script.

```
    nw,d,nm,year,date,mns,arm,age,gender,rc,city,state,sg
    x,x,pac,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,53,Male,A,Shelton,WA,x
    x,x,ces,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,53,Female,A,Shelton,WA,x
    x,x,ret,2015,2015-01-06,sur,ml apon,53,Male,A,Shelton,OR,x
    x,x,set,2015,2015-01-02,sur,les,47,Male,W,Aloha,OR,x
    x,x,wem,2015,2015-01-04,sur,ml apon,32,Male,W,San Francisco,CA,x
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I´m learning bash it´s first time, I know more or less how to use sed, but I dont know how to do what im asking. I have and a idea that the only way of get it done is with a BEGIN and using AWK

Comment: @markp-fuso It refers to gender, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this task:

```sh
mlr --csv count -g 'state,gender' file.csv
```

```
state,gender,count
WA,Male,1
WA,Female,1
OR,Male,2
CA,Male,1
```

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR>1 { counts[$12 OFS $9]++ }
END   { for (i in counts) print i,counts[i] }
' data.csv
```

This generates:

```
CA,Male,1
WA,Male,1
OR,Male,2
WA,Female,1
```

If the output needs to be sorted (eg, by state and then gender):

```
$ awk -F, '...code_from_above...' data.csv | sort -t ',' -k1,2
CA,Male,1
OR,Male,2
WA,Female,1
WA,Male,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little ruby to do this:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
puts "state,gender,count"
CSV.parse($<.read, **{:col_sep=>",", :headers=>true}).
group_by{ |r| [r["state"], r["gender"]] }.
each{ |k,v| puts "#{k.join(",")},#{v.length()}" }
' file
```

Prints:

```
state,gender,count
WA,Male,1
WA,Female,1
OR,Male,2
CA,Male,1
```